# Rotate beyond 360 with transition

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/DB1500/pen/obRMPw).

On clicking the button, I toggle the class `'in-view'` and the "bars" transform into an "X" by rotating the :before and :after 45deg and -45deg respectively, while making the middle bar transparent. I thought it would look cool to spin an extra 360 before finishing in this position, (therefore I want them to rotate a total of 405deg). However, it seems to only rotate the 45deg still? Any ideas why?

```
<div class="menu-button">
    <div></div>
</div>

.menu-button div.in-view {
    background: transparent;
}
.menu-button div.in-view:before,
.menu-button div.in-view:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-405deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-405deg);
}
.menu-button div.in-view::after {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(405deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(405deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a start rotate value

```
.menu-button div::before,
.menu-button div::after {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0); /* here */
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VeOBJQ)

Comment: legend! I presumed there would be a default rotate(0) in place.